# Why my animations works in a strange way?

Tags: qt, qml

I have write a simple animation demo,but the animation work in a strange way.

**The Code**

```js
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 480
    height: 680
    id: root

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "blue"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        states: State {
            name: "A"
            when: mouseArea.pressed
            PropertyChanges {target: rect; color:"red"; }
            PropertyChanges {target: rect; width: rect.width + 100}
            PropertyChanges {target: rect; rotation: 720}
        }

        transitions: Transition {
            ColorAnimation {duration: 1000}
            NumberAnimation {duration: 1000}
            RotationAnimation {duration: 1000}
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

}
```

**Q1**: When mouse press and hold, I want the rectange `width` increase 100 every time,but my code seems not work?
**Q2**: If the `width` assign a const value(eg 100), the `NumberAnimation` seems not work, the width change immediately?
**Q3**:The `RotationAnimation` not rotate 720, it rotate exceed 720?

Currently, I am not familiar with `js&qml`, Hope Good Man(Woman) can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: You shouldn't bind rect.width to itself. That causes a binding loop. Either use a constant value or come up with some way outside of rect to keep track of what size you want the rect to be.

Q2: You need to tell the NumberAnimation which property to animate on. In this case it's "width".

Q3: 720 degrees means twice all the way around. That's exactly what I'm seeing when I test it, so I think it's working correctly.

The code below works for me.

```
    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "blue"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        states: State {
            name: "A"
            when: mouseArea.pressed
            PropertyChanges {target: rect; color:"red"; }
            PropertyChanges {target: rect; width: 300} // Fixed value
            PropertyChanges {target: rect; rotation: 720}
        }

        transitions: Transition {
            ColorAnimation {duration: 1000}
            NumberAnimation {property: "width"; duration: 1000} // Specify property
            RotationAnimation {duration: 1000}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from JarMan, I think you want to define a `onPressed` handler in the `MouseArea`, where you assign a new value to the width of the rect (note the difference between "binding" and "assigning"):

```
MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    anchors.fill: parent

    onPressed: rect.width += 100
}
```

To clarify why that `PropertyChange` on `width` didn't work: as long as State "A" is active (thus during the mouse press), the `PropertyChange` overwrites the binding in the original `Rectangle` code, and you are defining it as a binding, meaning during the "A" state, the width is bound to itself (the binding loop that JarMan writes about). When state "A" is not active anymore, it will return to `width: 300` (which is basically also a binding, albeit being constant).

When you use the above `onPressed` handler, the `width` property will loose it's binding and become fixed to the value assigned to it. Note: you can make it bound again by using [Qt.binding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html#creating-property-bindings-from-javascript) or temporarily by using another `PropertyChanges` from a State